# Does the SPDY protocol eliminate the need for cookieless domains?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, spdy

With plain HTTP, cookieless domains are an optimization to avoid unnecessarily sending cookie headers for page resources.

However, the SPDY protocol compresses HTTP headers and in some cases eliminates unnecessary headers. My question then is, does SPDY make cookieless domains irrelevant?

Furthermore, should the page source and all of its resources be hosted at the same domain in order to optimize a SPDY implementation?

Answer (score 5):

> Does SPDY make cookieless domains irrelevant?

Sort of, mostly... But not entirely.

First off, there are at least two good reasons for using "cookieless domains": one is to avoid the extra headers and reduce the size of the request, second is to avoid leaking any private or secure information about the user. Each is valid independent of each other. So with that, clearly there is still a reason to have a "cookieless domain" under HTTP 2.0 for security and privacy.

Further, compression is not a magic bullet either. Establishing a compression / decompression context is not free, and depending on the used compression scheme, allocated buffer sizes, etc, a large cookie could completely destroy the performance of the compressor. Up to spdy/v3, a gzip compressor (sliding window) was used, and given a large enough cookie, you *would* have  a negative impact on performance of the compressor (degree varies by browser, based on implementation). In spdy/v4, the gzip compressor is out and an entirely new algorithm is being implemented from scratch -- since v4 is not out yet, it's too early to speculate about the specifics of performance. Having said that, in most cases, you should be fine.. I'm just highlighting the edge cases.

> Furthermore, should the page source and all of its resources be hosted at the same domain in order to optimize a SPDY implementation?

Yes, to the extent possible - that'll give you best performance. There are caveats here as well: high packet loss to origin server, or high BDP product without window scaling. But chances are, if you're using a reasonable hosting provider with good connectivity, neither of these should be an issue.